# Issue with replacing special characters

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

Im having a issue with removing special characters from the string .I used the following code.But dint work.Please suggest me better logic

```
- (NSString *)trimmedReciString:(NSString *)stringName 
{
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-/:;()$&@\".,?!\'[]{}#%^*+=_|~<>€£¥•."];
    for (int i = 0; i < [stringName length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [stringName characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[stringName characterAtIndex:i]]);
            stringName =  [stringName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[stringName characterAtIndex:i]] withString:@""];  

        }
    }
    return stringName;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString *s = @"$$$hgh$g%k&fg$$tw/-tg";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-/:;()$&@\".,?!\'[]{}#%^*+=_|~<>€£¥•."];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"String is: %@", s);
```

Comment: nice one i tested this code output is String is: hghgkfgtwtg +1 for simply solution

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
NSString *unfilteredString = @"!@#$%^&*()_+|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString = [[unfilteredString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog (@"Result: %@", resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting from the ***end*** of the string and work backwards instead of going from front to back, since you're likely to accidentally (and unintentionally) skip characters when the previous character gets deleted.