# How to remove some character from NSString in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, replace, nsstring

```
NSString *Address = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
NSLog(@"Address:%@", Address);
Address: ("Hooker Alley","San Francisco, CA 94108",USA)
```

I want to remove some character from Address string like Hooker Alley, San Francisco, CA 94108,USA.
How to remove like this? please help me

Thanks in  Advance

I tried this:

```
NSString *removeCharacter = [Address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
```

But the error comes in First throw call stack:

Error Message is,

```
-[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81afd00
```

Comment: What is the exact error? and please try to use "address" instead of "Address" for variable names. It is so confusing with the class names and data type names.

Comment: -[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81afd00

Comment: Your adress variable is returning a array

Comment: That means "Address" is not a string and it is returning an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSArray *addressArray = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
NSString *address = [addressArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"Address:%@", address);
```

In your case, `[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]` is returning an array and not a single string. You can try to join these array components as a single string as shown above. Alternatively you can also check

```
id object = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
if([object isKindOfClass[NSArray class]]) {
  //handle as above
} else if([object isKindOfClass[NSString class]]) {
  //use your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove like:-

```
 NSString *s = @"$$$hgh$g%k&fg$$tw/-tg";
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-/:;()$&@\".,?!\'[]{}#%^*+=_|~<>€£¥•."];
    s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

    NSLog(@"String is: %@", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what output does `addressDictionary objectForKey` provides using `isKindOfClass` like this:

```
if([[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] isKindOfClass[NSArray class]])
{

  NSArray *address=[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
  NSLog(@"Address:%@",Address);
  NSString *str = [address componentsJoinedByString: @","]
  NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once....It will help you

```
 NSString *unfilteredString = @"!@#$%^&*()_+|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"];
NSString *resultString = [[unfilteredString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog (@"Result: %@", resultString);
```

Comment: This won't yield the required output. Same answer not work always. This will work for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487931/issue-with-replacing-special-characters/13488065#13488065

Comment: I post this answer because in question Minu said that "Address is a string"...If it is a string it will work.

Comment: It's ok. But where is the ( ) in the not allowed character list ? She want to remove the ( ) and not the numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray *Address=[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
     NSLog(@"Address:%@",Address);

     NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < [Address count] ; i++){
    [myString appendString:[Address objectAtIndex:i]];


    if (i < [Address count]  ){
    [myString appendString:@","];
       }
 }

NSLog(@"%@",myString);
```

Comment: Why [reinvent the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel)? why not just use `[Address componentsJoinedByString:@", "]`?